# Offset on op amp output

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, integrator, 741-opamp, analog-computer

I am building an integrator circuit on a breadboard using an LM741 op-amp. Below is the circuit diagram: [image]

The input to the circuit is a 10 kHz signal with a peak to peak of 1 volt (with 0 offset). The circuit integrates the signal (input: sine wave, output: cos wave ...... input: square wave, output: triangle wave, ect) I am using an oscilloscope to look at and measure the output. I have the power supply connected in series so the op amp has +12, and -12 V, with the non inverting input connected to 0 V.

---

The problem is, the output wave is offset by a voltage of around 6 V(it varies if I adjust the voltage on the power supply). The peak to peak is as expected on the output. But I can not figure out how to get rid of the output offset?

Comment: In maths, any integration generates a \$+c\$ constant, that's the offset you see :) Apart from the joke, it might depend on the start phase.

Comment: Your power supply network on the right of the schematics looks quite absurd.  What lines (and labels) do you use on your board, what lines on your power supply?

Comment: @RohatKılıç R2 stops this from being an integrator.  Start phase DC offset is removed; the RC feedback network has a time constant of 1s, corresponding to a 0.15Hz lowcut.

Comment: Mandatory read on 741 usage: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp

Comment: @winny Max bias current 1.5µA.  On 40k|100k, this is probably good for 50mV.  Which is bad but nowhere near 6V.  DC amplification is 2.5.  Still nowhere near 6V.

Comment: Please provide oscillograms of IN+, IN- and OUT pins with reference to your ground. Do you have any decoupling on the power supply pins?

Comment: Why have you shorted out all your power supplies on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the output to be centred on 0 V the input waveform must have a negative going excursion exactly the same as its positive going excursion. There will be an output offset if the input's positive going excursion is different in amplitude or different in time to its negative going excursion.

Comment: 6V is half the power supply voltage.  This is more likely to be a misunderstanding about how to supply ±12V.

Comment: @user107063 Half the supply voltage would be 12V if it's actually a bipolar supply as shown. They may have a total of 12V and are calling it ±12V when it's actually ±6V though.

Answer (score 4):

> *I am building an integrator circuit on a breadboard using an LM741
> op-amp.*

This is the pin allocation for a 741 slop-amp: -

[image]

- You have assumed your output is on pin 1 and this is wrong.
- You have also assumed the power pin is pin 8 and this is also wrong

[image]

- I won't bother mentioning the other things folk have said.